# Confused about timecode/fps results when using avconv/avprobe

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libav

I'm using `avprobe` to get information about timecode and fps from videos. Getting the information isn't a problem but I'm a bit confused as to the result. When running avprobe on an H.264 file I'm seeing fps listed at 25 and the duration of the clip as 00:03:29.81. My understanding is that the number after the decimal point is frames, but this doesn't make sense since it's 25 fps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ffmpeg and avconv, the number after the decimal point is [in fractions of a second](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax), i.e. centiseconds if given with two digits.

> ```
> [-][HH:]MM:SS[.m...]
> ```
>
> HH expresses the number of hours, MM the number of minutes for a maximum of 2 digits, and SS the number of seconds for a maximum of 2 digits. The m at the end expresses decimal value for SS.